# Некорректно работает парсер на python

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Вот код моего парсера. Он просто собирает ссылки с сайта и пишет их в файл.

Но есть но:

1. Почему он собирает не все ссылки - из 500 урлов видит примерно 50?
2. Некоторые ссылки пишет по 2-3 раза.

Что не так?

```
def get_books() -> typing.List[str]:
    rs = requests.get('https:.......')
    root = BeautifulSoup(rs.text, 'html.parser')

    t = []
    for x in root.findAll('a'):
        try:
            t1 = x["href"].strip()
            if not 'http' in t1:
                t1 = 'https://......' + t1
            t.append(t1)
        except KeyError:
            pass
    return t


if __name__ == '__main__':
    books = get_books()
    f = io.open('parsed_data.htm', 'w', encoding='utf8')
    i = 1
    for line in books:
        f.write(line + "\n")
    f.close()

    tf = io.open('text1.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8')
    with open('parsed_data.htm', 'r') as f:
        file = f.readlines()

    seen_item = []
    for line in file:
        if line not in seen_item:
            seen_item.append(line)
            tf.write(line)
    tf.close()
```

Comment: Ну видимо из 500 урлов только 50 попадают под ваши условия в коде...

Comment: 1) Возможно сам сайт динамически подгружает новые данные с ссылками 2) Возможно ссылки дублируются на странице в разных контекстах 3) Код вызывает некоторые вопросы, но выглядит рабочим, поэтому предоставьте ссылку для отработки алгоритма и ваш результат в `books`

Comment: @ Эникейщик  Я проверял, условия те же... По поводу дубляжа, вопрос решился, а вот с неполным...